# wso2esb - project management

Tags: wso2-esb

I evaluate SOA products of wso2 for few weeks and there are some basic (and crucial to me) features which I cannot find/use or maybe it just does not exist. I want to make sure.

First of all, creating IDE support. As probably most of you know wso2 team delivers Carbon Studio which is quite a nice thing. Unfortunately when it comes to team work so often importing existing projects into IDE I hit a wall because:

1) If I use Distribution Project I'm required to commit .projects files which actually contains nature understand by Carbon Studio. It is acceptable but it is as well bad practice in my opinion.

2) If I use Maven then after import I'm going to loose project nature so plugins are not going to work without preparing .projects.

Am I missing something? I would like get rid of .projects and be able to use IDE on 100%. Is it possible? Can't it be generated or something. Normally plugins are trying to recognize file type and edit it with specified plugin. I understand that most Synapse configs (for example) are all XMLs but that is not a reason for me. Any way, does someone know some kind of solution?

Also Distribution Project cannot be build from command line if known maven repositories cannot deliver some artifact. I can write maven plugin to implicitly build each wanted artifact but it is not something I want to do if maven can do it for me. And I cannot use maven because after import I'll lose IDE features.

To me IDE is useless if I'm required to fix each project before actually importing it. Time is very precious.

The second important and unacceptable feature is importing jars into project when using, for example, generators. Why created project cannot be configured to use dependencies?

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is the developer studio version you use? From developer studio 2.0.0 there is a feature to import a carbon project. Then you don't need to commit the .project files.

Goto import --> WSO2 --> Existing WSO2 projects into workspace